# How do I rank certain characters?

Tags: c++

I want to rank characters based on operator precedence. I'm not sure what the most efficient way to do that would be. Should I map the characters to numbers from greatest to least? Maybe use a union find data structure?

Comment: What about characters used for more than one operator precedence level, like `-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it sounds like the characters that you would like to rank represent operators, I am assuming that the number of characters that you would like to map is small. If all these characters are regular 8-bit `char`s, you could simply define an array of 256 numbers representing the precedence:

```
uint8_t precedence[256] = { 0 };
precedence['*'] = 1;
precedence['/'] = 1;
precedence['%'] = 1;
precedence['+'] = 2;
precedence['-'] = 2;
precedence['!'] = 2;
precedence['~'] = 2;
precedence['&'] = 3;
precedence['^'] = 4;
precedence['|'] = 5;
```

**Note:** The characters I used for this example will be positive in the encodings that are relevant today. However, if you use other characters or exotic encodings, and some of the characters that you use for indexes are negative, you need to add a cast to avoid undefined behavior:

```
precedence[(uint8_t)'|'] = 5;
```

Comment: Will cause undefined behaviour if any of those characters have negative values